# What's the difference between rack app vs. rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack

I uploaded my rails 2.3.8 app to DreamHost and got an error about rack version incompatibility.
I issued a support ticket and the service guy recommended that I delete config.ru.

That solved the problem. But I wonder what that would affect.

Is it ok that a rails app goes without config.ru?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Rack app is a web app written in Ruby that uses the [Rack](http://rack.rubyforge.org/) project. A really simple Hello World `config.ru` example is like so:

```
class HelloWorld
  def call(env)
    [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, ['Hello World!']]
  end
end

run HelloWorld.new
```

Rails 2.3+ uses Rack as the basis for its HTTP handling, but some hosting providers might handle Rails specially and may not support running Rails as a Rack app. That seems to be the case with DreamHost for Rails 2.3.8, at least as you've specified your gem requirements.

Comment: I had to use `{'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}` instead of `{'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}` (mind the `=>`/`:` change)

Answer (score 4):

you should check those two RailsCasts:

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/151-rack-middleware
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/150-rails-metal
- and perhaps: http://railscasts.com/episodes/222-rack-in-rails-3