# What is Ruby's counterpart to Java's web.xml?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I'm working with [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) for the first time and was able to successfully [install](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall) it locally. I haven't used Ruby before and I come from a Java background.

I am able to run the application by going to -

```
http://localhost:3000/projects
```

The question is, where can I find the html file (if it exists) that corresponds to `http://localhost:3000/projects`. In Java, we can do this by looking at web.xml or the relevant Spring configuration file and see how the URL is mapped to a servlet or controller. How to do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Note that Ruby is not the same as Rails.

Ruby, like Java, is a programming language. It appeared in 1995. For example, the following is a script/program you can execute from the command line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
puts "Hello World"
```

[Rack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rack_(web_server_interface)) is a web server interface for Ruby. It handles the HTTP protocol, and allows one to write web applications in Ruby by making it easy to parse HTTP requests and send HTTP responses.

Rails is a web framework with powerful conventions, patterns, and tools for developing web applications in Ruby. [Some part of it uses Rack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230904/whats-the-difference-between-rack-app-vs-rails-app). It appeared in 2004. [Sinatra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinatra_(software)) is an example of another web framework that uses Rack.

#### What's the equivalent of `web.xml` in Ruby?

It does not exist.

#### What's the equivalent of `web.xml` in Rack?

Probably `config.ru`.

#### What's the equivalent of `web.xml` in Rails?

`config/routes.rb` and `config/application.rb`. Please refer to [Configuring Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html).

### Routes

To figure out which html file corresponds to `http://localhost:3000/projects`, look in `config/routes.rb`. If you see

```
resources :projects
```

then it is handled by the index action in ProjectsController with the view at `app/views/projects/index.*`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. OP's question was "What's Ruby's counterpart to Java's web.xml". This answers that question. However, I also updated my answer to include information about resource routes.

Comment: The question is "The question is, where can I find the html file (if it exists) that corresponds to http://localhost:3000/projects". Title is misleading because OP has no idea how Rails works and loves configuring his XMLs.

Answer (score 2):

The counterpart of web.xml is the routes.rb and the config.rb files in ruby. You'll find them in the config directory. The routes.rb defines which controller and action (much like servlets) will handle a certain request (URL). And since Rails has predefined conventions, all the html files go in the folders named after the controllers in the views directory and by convention the html file with the same name as that of the controller's action that has been invoked will be rendered as the response.

But all of this can be overridden if desired.

This is a nice place to start understanding Rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 1):

Rails follows convention over configuration principle so all views can always be found in

```
app/views/
```

and the one you are looking for should be (depending on Redmine template processor)

```
app/views/projects/index.html.erb
```

Also a convention is that view files are named like

```
path/to/view/_action_name_._content_type_._processor_
```

Comment: I see index.api.rsb and index.html.erb

Answer (score 1):

In Rails you can find all the mappings to the routes of your web app looking at the routes.rb file in the config folder inside your project folder.

For example, if you want to configure the index page in your project, remove the index.html.erb in the public folder and do like:

```
root :to => "yourController#someAction"
```

Understanding routes is not an easy task for someone coming from a Java background. But [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) should help.